# How can I get the line-number of an error in a dynamically added <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, line-numbers, dynamic-script-loading

When dynamically creating a script element and adding it to the page, my errors are not giving me line numbers of the script, but instead the line number where I append the script.

The code below when in a .js file will give you a line number error of whichever line `document.appendChild(script)` is on.  The code snippet, if ran, will return the correct line number.  How do they do this?

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\nfoo.bar";  //error should be on line 8

document.head.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336082/the-searchbar-works-better-with-tags-than-questions-explaining-this-could-reduc?noredirect=1#comment403450_336082

Comment: something came up in the sidebar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838067/catch-js-errors-when-adding-a-script-dynamically?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Adding a try catch around the code works great

```
catchableScript = function(scriptText) {
    var scriptText = "try {\n"+scriptText+"\n} \n catch(ex){console.log(ex.lineNumber-1)}";

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = scriptText;

    document.head.appendChild(script)

}

catchableScript("\n\n\n\n\n\n\nfoo.bar");
```

Output: `8`

Also, the exception has more information which is useful, but this is the answer to the question.

EDIT:

For those who want it, adding this code:

```
window.CURRENTLY_EVALED_SCRIPT = scriptText;
var scriptText = "try {\n"+scriptText
    +"\n} catch(ex){\n"
    +"var lineNumber = ex.lineNumber-1;\n"
    +"var errorOut = {};\n"
    +"errorOut.exception = ex;\n"
    +"errorOut.lines = window.CURRENTLY_EVALED_SCRIPT.split('\\n');\n"
    +"var line = errorOut.lines[lineNumber-1];\n"
    +"console.log(ex.message+' on line\\n'+line+' :: '+lineNumber, window.CURRENTLY_EVALED_SCRIPT_ELEMENT, errorOut);\n"
            +"}";

    ...

window.CURRENTLY_EVALED_SCRIPT_ELEMENT = script
```

Will result in this output in console:

```
foo is not defined on line
foo.bar :: 8, <script>, Object { exception: ReferenceError, lines: Array[8] }
```

And you can click `<script>` to go to appended element, or `lines` to just see an array of all the lines.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "line number", you probably mean the line number of a file. But in this case, which file is it? You're creating the script dynamically, so there really isn't one.

The script you're creating lives only in the DOM, i.e. the in-memory representation of your code. It seems to be behaving exactly as I would expect.

Comment: I suppose so, but you can get a linenumber from an eval if you catch the error.  I'm currently checking if I can use window...onerror to catch it, then get the line number

Comment: nope.  window.onerror calls with just a string that is the error