# Execute js from string and get line number which failed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am executing js which is stored as a string inside the db via:

```
let myScript = ` await Some()
lines()
of()
js()`

let result
try{
   result = await Object.getPrototypeOf(async function() {}).constructor(`return (async () => { ${myScript} })()`)()
} catch(e){
   result = 'Error occurred: '+e.message + ' stack: ' + e.stack
}
```

The problem is: The line numbers of e.stack are not correct. I think it's somehow also counting line numbers of the contextual code. For some js strings, I don't even get a stack.

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add try-catch block in your **string JS**, I hope the answer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121880/how-can-i-get-the-line-number-of-an-error-in-a-dynamically-added-script-tag) will help you.